# Twitter cuts my urls with a high hand

Tags: php, utf-8, twitter, urlencode, utf8-decode

I want to enable user can tweet songs they like in [**demo**](http://cruisear.com/test2.php) However, when url contains a Turkish character Twitter splits the url from just after the first Turkish character like on image
[image]
Url on tweet must be like `myurl.com/?view=s&artist=demet%20akıalın&track=ışık%20hğzmesi`
 but it is cutted right after `demet ak`

codes i use is here:

```
<?php
    define('APP_BASE_URL', 'http://www.myurl.com');
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    $a['artistname'] = 'demet akıalın';
    $a['trackname'] = 'ışık hğzmesi';
?> 

<a target="_blank" title="Share on Twitter" href="https://twitter.com/share?hashtags=CruisEar&text=<?php echo $a['artistname']." - ".$a['trackname']; ?>&url=<?php echo urlencode(str_replace(" ","%20",APP_BASE_URL."?view=s&artist=".$a['artistname']."&track=".$a['trackname']));?>" data-url="https://dev.twitter.com" data-via="your_screen_name" data-lang="en"><img src="http://www.olmasigereken.com/demo2/img/twit.gif" alt="share on twitter" /></a>
```

Comment: Quote your array keys: `$a['artistname']`

Comment: i have quoted and edited my post but it isn't help

Comment: Didn't mean to imply it would fix your problem - just bugging me. You should be seeing a notice about *Use of undefined constant artistname - assumed 'artistname'*. Also, there's a very good reason all utf-8 chars aren't allowed in urls. Anyone could buy domains that look exactly like banking sites to phish for information. I.e. bankofamerica.com could actually go to a different server because even though it *looks* like the right url UTF-8 has enough lovely look-alike chars to make this a real security concern. You wouldn't know unless you checksum the url or something.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter is doing it right. According to the HTTP/1.1 specification, URLs cannot contain non-ASCII values and some ASCII values need to be percent-encoded.

The `ı` character is non-ASCII so it has to be percent-encoded, just like your space has to become `%20`

```
echo rawurlencode(utf8_encode(APP_BASE_URL.'?view=s&artist='.$a[artistname].'&track='.$a[trackname]));
```

Comment: What do you suggest for percent encoding?

Comment: @YouCanDoIt while urlencode() usually does a good job, I'd really suggest using rawurlencode(utf8_encode())

Comment: If ı use `rawurlencode(utf8_encode())` There is no url on tweet window

Comment: Oh, and if your data is already in utf-8, there's no need to convert it first.

Comment: Do not ever use `utf8_encode`, either make it so that your data is utf-8 in the first place, or find out what your data is (most likely never ISO-8859-1, which is what `utf8_encode` expects), and convert it from that to UTF-8

Comment: @Esailija Completely agree, servers should have their default encoding set to UTF-8 in which case this wouldn't be relevant at all. Sadly, a lot of servers out there have their encodings set to ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt In that context ISO-8859-1 is actually a mislabel for Windows-1252. But `utf8_decode/encode` expects actual ISO-8859-1.